How to notify blazor(webassembly) about DOM changes made from js?
I'm trying to reduce render count of a very heavy component which renders thousands of spans. I can't apply virtualization because spans have different size.
<div contenteditable="true">
    @foreach (var item in els)
    {
        <span @key="@item.Key" class="@item.cssClass">@item.String</span>
    }
</div>

I made an attempt to replace span by a component which renders span and it works, but initial render time was taking too long.
I can't do everything via js and disable rerender because root div may contain some other blazor components.
I need to apply some changes via JS without rerender, but at some time rerender happens and render state is corrupted. How can I notify blazor about changes in dom?
Or maybe I need to revert all changes made from js before render?
Change types:

modify span's textContent
split span at some offset
add span into div

Do I need to use something like node.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))?
Are there any possible problems here?

If an element rendered by Blazor is modified externally using JS directly or via JS Interop, the DOM may no longer match Blazor's internal representation, which can result in undefined behavior. Undefined behavior may merely interfere with the presentation of elements or their functions but may also introduce security risks to the app or server. You can learn more from this website:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#interaction-with-the-dom

But I asked how to avoid this undefined behavior. I can probably undo all JS changes before rendering the new tree. And I wonder why it is impossible to synchronize Blazor state with the DOM using things like mutationobservers?

Blazor does not provide a built-in mechanism to notify the .NET runtime about DOM changes made by JavaScript, or to synchronize arbitrary JS changes with the Blazor app state. The framework is not designed for this and such practices are generally not recommended.
What you can do is call a C# .NET method with JSInterop after doing the JavaScript changes. Provide information about the changes to the .NET runtime and then for each of the possible change types do the following, is applicable:

Modify <span> content: find the correct item in the els collection and change its String property value.
Split <span> at some offset: replace the corresponding item in the els collection with two new items with the correct String values.
Add <span> to <div>: add a new item to els.

When doing the server-side changes, you can override the ShouldRender() method of your component and temporarily disable re-rendering, because the DOM in the browser is already up-to-date.
Update: Note that it may not be always possible to achieve perfect synchronization between the server-side app state with the DOM state. For example, Blazor uses empty HTML comments <!-- --> to distinguish components and their parts. The JavaScript DOM changes may break this mechanism. If this occurs, the only option is to remove the whole <div> with all <span>s temporarily with server-side code and re-render everything from scratch.

Yes I do exactly the same thing. On char insert I modify dom and dot net model with ShouldRender false. It works. But after some time I need to rerender control and sometimes it inserts duplicated spans and so on. And I'm trying to find a way how to discard this.

Updated my response.

Thanks. I'll accept that as response. But could you tell me is there any docs or source code where described how this "shadow dom" and sync with dom works? And main question, my spans are not custom controls so as i understand there are no comments in them. So how blazor knows which element matches current key? Does it add some attribute to the node? How ElementReference works, is there some map between id and html node?

I fond source code, and I have shallow understanding how it works. Unfortunately I need to spend a lot of time to understand it in details.  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Rendering/DomMerging/DomSync.ts#L422

The main problem with a single control with a lot of spans: it rerenders all spans which goes after an edited span, and Key doesn't work in that case.
But if we put every span into separate control it dramatically reduces render speed.
So I decided to split spans to batches. I marked some spans as batch start and they are the same even after edits. So spans now grouped and only one group will be rerendered after edit. Actually we can change group size and select split granularity. And probably i would be better to change GetHashCode to some good hash.
SpanGroup.razor
@foreach (var item in Spans)
{
    <span class="@item.CssClass">@item.String</span>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public IReadOnlyList<Element> Spans { get; set; } = [];

}

Text.razor:
@foreach (var group in els.Grouped())
{
    <SpanGroup @key="@group.Key" Spans="group.Spans"></SpanGroup>
}

public static IEnumerable<Group> Grouped(this IEnumerable<Element> textElements, int groupSize = 10) {

    var accum = new List<Element>(groupSize);
    
    foreach (var element in textElements) {
        var isGroupStart = element.Key.GetHashCode() % groupSize == 0;
        if (isGroupStart && accum.Count > 0) {

            yield return new Group
            {
                Spans = accum,
                Key = accum[0].Key
            };

            accum = new List<Element>(groupSize);
        }
        accum.Add(element);
    }
    if (accum.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return new Group
        {
            Spans = accum,
            Key = accum[0].Key
        };
    }
}

